# How can I update an array in state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When my app loads I generate some initial data. My initial state is:

`const INITIAL_STATE = { calendarData: [ ], index: 0 }`

The data generated is an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2017-09-24T16:13:24.419Z",
    "id": 0,
    "swiped": false,
    "uri": "http://www.someurl.com/24.png",
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-25T16:13:24.426Z",
    "id": 1,
    "swiped": false,
    "uri": "http://www.someurl.com/25.png",
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-26T16:13:24.426Z",
    "id": 2,
    "swiped": false,
    "uri": "http://www.someurl.com/26.png",
  }
]
```

I'm attempting to update `calendarData` like so:

```
return {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]};
```

However, when I log mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { calendarData: state.calendarData };
};
```

Console shows the following:

```
Object {
  "calendarData": Object {
    "calendarData": Array [],
    "index": 0,
  },
```

I am trying to update the empty calendarData array in INITIAL_STATE with the new array of objects.

Before I made this change I was initializing `state = []` and returning the `aboveArray`, which worked. Now I want my state to be an object that has a calendarData array and an index key,

```
state = {
    calendarData: [],
    index: 0,
}
```

Comment: Does your answer require updating the same array objects if the array is not empty?

Comment: At some point, the array of objects will be replaced with new objects. So the objects themselves won't be updated (at this time at least).

Comment: How are mapStateToProps and return {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]}; called?

Comment: `return {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]};` needs to be used to define state, not calendarData

Comment: Do you mind expanding on what you mean it needs to define state? I feel as if I'm close to wrapping redux around my head, but not there yet :)

Comment: `INITIAL_STATE = {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]}` instead of `calendarData= {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]}`

Comment: Do you mind providing an example of this in a reducer? I'm sorry I don't follow your solution.

Comment: make sure your reducer also is like this -> export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

Comment: Your code is very hard to interpret because you're giving us single lines of code and not explicitly telling us where they exist. If you're having troubles with redux from a fundamentals standpoint, we need to know things like where you are placing this statement: `return {...state, calendarData: [...state.calendarData, ...aboveArray]};`

Comment: ```return { ...state, calendarData: state.calendarData.concat(aboveArray) }```